# Executar duas funções com onclick

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso executar duas funções com onClick, mas não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Eu quero esconder a div pai "introductionAds" e mostrar a div "mostrarID"

```js
function ocultar(ocultarID){
    document.getElementById(ocultarID).style.display='none';
}
function mostrar(mostrarID){
    document.getElementById(mostrarID).style.display='block';
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id='introductionAds'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" target='_blank' class='' id="link1"> Link habilitado </a></li>
    <li><a href="" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link2"> Link habilitado </a></li>
    <li><a href="" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link3"> Link habilitado </a></li>
    <li><a href="" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link4"> Link habilitado </a></li>
    <li><a href="" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link5" onclick="this.onclick=function(){mostrar('mostrarID');ocultar('introductionAds');}"> Link habilitado </a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>

<div id='mostrarID' style='display:none;'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adicione ponto e virgula no final para chamar as funções, (será chamado em ordem)

```
 <input id="botao" type="button" value="click" onclick="ocultarID(); mostrarID();"/>
```

Comment: Guilherme essa foi a minha primeira tentativa e por incrivel que pareça não funciona, porem perceba que eu quero executar a função em um link e não em um botão. Pra vc ter umaideia tente colocar o meu script num editor e executa pra vc ver, não funfiona assim, pelo menos deveria.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, se eu entendi certo, vc vai esconder uma e mostrar a outra no mesmo momento. Então pode colocar tudo numa função só. Ficaria assim:

```html
function mostrar (){
  document.getElementById('mostrarID').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('introductionAds').style.display = 'none';
}
```

E não precisa passar nada como parâmetro, o JS busca o id no HTML. Tenta assim, se não for isso q vc quer, só avisar.

Comment: Junior também já tentei isso e só oculta a div introductionAds mas não mostra a div mostrarID. Só pra ter certeza acabei de tentar isso ai de novo mas nada ainda. Não entendo porque não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também transcrever essa função em uma só:

```
function mostrar(id, show){
    var show = (show) ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display=show;
}

mostrar('introductionAds', true);
mostrar('introductionAds', false);
```

Comment: Guilherme acabei de testar aqui e também não funciona veja no link abaixo:

Comment: Também não funcionou, confira http://jsfiddle.net/p3Bht/74/